# React router 4 - detect if one of child route matches in a parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using react router 4 to display a list of users. The component `Users` loads when the route matches `\Users`. Inside that, I have a `Route` defined (user details) that's loaded when the URL matches `\Users\:id`.

The `Users` page has a grid/table with few columns.

```
render(){
    const {users, flags} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Users</h3>
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <UsersGrid users={this.state.users} />
            </div>
            <Route path="/users/:id" component={UserDetail} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I want is if the user details route is active then to shrink the user grid (say apply class col-md-4) and show the user detail to its right.

But I am not sure how can I detect if a child route is active so that I can conditionally apply a class to an element. I tried using `this.props.children` but it is always undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would make use of `matchPath` from react-router

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

render(){
    const {users, flags, location } = this.props;
    const match = matchPath(location.pathname, {
       path: '/users/:id',
       exact: false,
       strict: false
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Users</h3>
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <UsersGrid users={this.state.users} />
            </div>
            <Route path="/users/:id" component={UserDetail} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If url shows in address bar then you can check with window.location if it contains string like id after /user then perform action with condition check:

```
        if(/user/{anyid}) {
         *your condition action*
        } else {
         *else action*
        }
```

you can use string regex to match the id.